# function doesn't work in script shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

I'm learning scripting shell in Linux. And now I have some problems with the creation of a function. I'm working on CentOS.

This is the function's code:

```
#votolaurea.lib
votolaurea() {
voto=$(($voto * 11))
voto=$((voto /3))
echo "Il voto sarà $voto";
}
```

And this is the script who call that function

```
#!/bin/bash
~/imieiscript/votolaurea.lib
echo "Give me the number"
read media
echo 'votolaurea.lib $media'
```

But the output is:

```
Give me the number
3 //this is my number in input
votolaurea.lib $media
```

It doesn't call the function but it prints all the command. Why?

Comment: That's what `echo` does, print its arguments. Try `votolaurea.lib $media` only.

Comment: At the start and at the end of the every code in this post, there are this symbols ' but there aren't in the real code. I have done a bad formatting.

Comment: @pfnuesel I've tried how you've suggest me but I have this error "votolaurea.lib:command not found"

Comment: If you have a function called `votolaurea` in a file called `votolaurea.lib` (which is a strange filename for a shell script) and you want to execute that function with the value of `$media` as an argument then you must first source the file: `. votolaurea.lib`, and then call the function: `votolaurea "$media"`. Note that the names of the file and the function have nothing to do with eachother (even if they, in this case, happen to have some similarities).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I interpreted correctly your code, you created two files:

- one named `votolaurea.lib`, containing the function `votolaurea`;
- the other one unspecified (let's call it `test.sh`).

Remember that:

- in order to use inside `test.sh` any function (or other definitions) present in `votolaurea.lib`, you need to *source it* using the `source` command (or its equivalent `.`);
- single-quoted strings are not processed by the shell but are left unchanged; therefore if you want to call function `votolaurea()` you have to put it outside of the quoted string;
- parameters are passed to functions using the positional parameters `$1`, `$2`, etc.

Taking into account of the previous points, you should apply some changes to your code.

#### votolaurea.lib

```
#votolaurea.lib
votolaurea() {
    echo $(($1 * 11 / 3 ))
}
```

#### test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
source ~/imieiscript/votolaurea.lib
echo "Give me the number"
read media
echo "Il voto sarà $(votolaurea $media)";
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Now it works. But I haven't understood the reason why I can't write, in the file "votolaurea.lib", my instructions in a only one line. You have edit my code rewriting my three instructions in only one. Why?

Comment: You can write your code using intermediate steps: it's obviously legal and supported. Just be sure to use the correct variable names for the passed arguments, e.g.:

`votolaurea() {
    voto=$(($1 * 11));
    voto=$((voto / 3));
    echo $voto
    }`

However I suggest you to make `votolaurea()` just return the computed value (as in my examples) and leave the text formatting to the main script.

Answer (score 0):

To execute a string as a command, you should use ``` `` ``` or `$()`:

```
echo `votolaurea.lib $media`
echo $(votolaurea.lib $media)
```

Comment: I've tried but now I have this error: line 8: votolaurea.lib: command not found

Comment: Yeah, there are other issues my answer doesn't address. I think you should check out the answer of @davidedb, which seems rather complete, and accept it if your problem is solved.